# Simulate Record links (including compact layout hover) in Lightning component

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, compact-layout, lightning-base-component

In Visualforce you could add an `apex:outputLink` to a page and had a link that showed a **Mini layout on Hover**.

I want the exact same thing in a custom Lightning component. Add a record link and have a user customizable Compact layout to show up on Link hover.

[image]

**Is that doable and how? If not, why not or when?**

*I know that I could built that myself using a custom popover component and `lightning:recordViewForm`. But that is a lot of work and less flexible because there is no easy way to make the displayed fields customizable by users.*

Comment: I'd say there isn't such a thing. Even for `lightning:outputField`, the docs say "Lookups render as text only. Linking and hover overlays on lookup values are not supported."

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK There is no standard base lightning:component for a popover,

But you can use the one from the strike library:

http://www.lightningstrike.io/#!/strikePopover

**EDIT**

Another option: use [lightning:overlayLibrary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_lightning_overlayLibrary.htm) with the `showCustomPopover` method - that would set the visual popover, then inside it put your own fields

Comment: Hello, do you have any example on how to use the strike component for this? Thanks

Comment: @FranciscoRiccomagno I can see that their website is down, you can use their github repo: https://github.com/appiphony/Strike-Components search for the popover component. Unfortunately I do not have a working example of it